# Applet right click copy and past function

Tags: java, swing, security, applet, copy-paste

While leaning applet I found that its not possible to copy and past from system clipboard to applet textfiled. But changing JAVA permission we can perform copy and past using keyboard shortcut.How about mouse right click copy and past? I cant right click on applet now. It is possible right click copy and past on applet? How can I implement a right click menu and perform copy and past function?

Comment: thank you for link but how about mouse right click copy and past function

Comment: *"How about mouse right click copy and past?"* If you can get that working in a desktop app., it should work equally well in an applet (and I suggest you do that first). *"But changing JAVA permission we can perform copy and past using keyboard shortcut."* If an applet is fully trusted (by being signed with a valid certificate, the user accepting the code etc.) then it should be possible to combine the two successfully in an applet. BTW - Why code an applet?  ..

Comment: .. If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).